# Java, system architecture, correct implementation

Tags: java, architecture, implementation

I am not a java expert, and my question is somewhat abstract, i need an advice on how is a best to implement my suggested architecture and requirements.

I will describe my requirements:

I have a manager object that receives tasks to process (holds a a task queue), the manager should distribute tasks between dedicated threads. each thread knows to execute only specific type of tasks.

I created a Main Manager class with a collection of type specific threads, 
When a Main manager receives a new task it will push a task to the queue of a thread class object that knows how to handle this task (each thread has it's own task queue).

A thread need to pool a task from his queue when he finished to handle previous task, but if the queue is empty , he should not use resources and need to be awaken when a new task arrives.

My though (may be not so good) was to use threads that extend timer object and with a timed task of checking its queue, but this does not fit to my requirement to free resources until a new task arrives.

Any suggestion of the best way to handle those system requirement will be appreciated (My Question is not a homework but rather a part of my developing tasks).

**EDIT**

(An answer to @Alexander Torstling) I am using currently a Blocking Queue as a tasks queue, my question is not a concurrency issue but rather an architectural , i want to free resources when the queue is empty and i want to be awaken maybe by event if a new task arrives, if i have finished handling with a task and i have more of them i will continue to handle next task;

Comment: What about `java.util.concurrent` package? It contains a lot of useful classes that can solve a lot of your time.

Comment: @Michael: I must have misunderstood you. You say "if the queue is empty, he should not use resources". If you use a blocking queue, this is exactly what happens. The thread sleeps and uses no resources whatsoever. When a new task arrives it awakes immediately. Is this not the behavior you are seeing?

Comment: @Alexander Torstling: +1, I am sorry i haven't' understood all the capabilities of blocking queue and was using it wrongly, you are correct, and this is what i need (As i said i am not a java expert). just to clarify, if i have few more stuff to do but the queue is empty, will i sleep on queue.take() and will not continue to more processing statements?

Comment: have you taken a look at akka? http://akka.io/

Comment: @Michael: That is correct. When there are no available items when you call take() the thread will enter a passive state, like a sleep. This is usually referred to as a 'blocking' state or 'waiting' state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [BlockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html). And in order to avoid creating too many threads, you might want to consider using an [Executor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html), which can manage a thread pool for you.

Answer (score 1):

I would use an ExecutorService.  This wraps a Queue and a pool of Thread(s)

```
ExecutorService service = Executors.newXxxx(); // new thread pool.


service.submit(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        process(task);
    }
});
```

This way a single thread pool can process any number of different types of tasks (or just one if you prefer)

Comment: Ok, I see what you are suggesting, do you suggest that i will have executors per every task type, then the main manager will be responsible to submit the task to an executor? if the executor finished handling a task and i submitted him one more in the middle of execution, will he open another thread to execute it or will he execute it after he will end the execution of previous task?

Comment: I would use the smallest number of pools you need. One might be fine, but you can have one pool per task type in the most extreme case.  If you use a single thread pool or a fixed thread pool, it will only have the thread(s) you tell it to have. If you use a cached thread pool, it will create threads as needed.